# Java: for-loop doesnt seem to iterate in my method

Tags: java

This method Returns the index of the smallest element in the arrayOfInts, beginning the search from fromIndex. My returnVal is underlined in red and it says that my returnVal has not been initialized which tells me that my for-loop is not being iterated.

```
public static int findMin( int fromIndex, Integer[] arrayOfInts ) {

    int returnVal;
    int previousVal = arrayOfInts[fromIndex].intValue();

    for(int i = fromIndex; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++){

        if (arrayOfInts[fromIndex].intValue() <= previousVal){
            previousVal = arrayOfInts[fromIndex].intValue();
            returnVal = fromIndex;
        }
    }

    return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the sample datas with which you invoke this method?

Comment: The compiler cannot know whether `arrayOfInts.length > 0` (and the loop will be entered) which is why you're getting the error. You need to initialize the variable with `int returnVal = 0;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume by 'it' you mean the compiler. If it says the variable wasn't initialized, the solution is to initialize it:

```
 int returnVal = -1;
```

This is an example of [definite assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_assignment_analysis)

Comment: The return value should be an index, so perhaps `-1` (N/A) would be a better default.

Answer (score 1):

You interpret the message wrong. The for-loop **might** not be entered, if `arrayOfInts.length` = 0. And `arrayOfInts[fromIndex]` should be `arrayOfInts[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the returnVal variable. You can use any int value to do that. This is the reason why compiler is giving that error message